# Alexa: Requested skill error when selecting country

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I have a travel skill that gives me information on a country if it exists.  If it does not exist. I want to call the Travel Intent error message but it gives me 'there was a problem with the requested skill's response' Here is the example dialogue below:

```
User: "Alexa open travel costs"
Skill: " Welcome to the travel costs guide. Tell me what country you are going to and I will tell you how much you need on average to spend on food and accommodation. "
User: "how much is it to go to Mauritius"
Skill: "There was a problem with the requested skill's response"
```

index.js

```
var Alexa = require('alexa-sdk');

const APP_ID = '';

const skillData = [
    {
        country: "FRANCE",
        costs: "$175 is the average daily price for traveling in France. The average price of food for one day is $36. The average price of a hotel for a couple is $206"
    },
    {
        country: "SPAIN",
        costs: "$135 is the average daily price for traveling in Spain. The average price of food for one day is $32. The average price of a hotel for a couple is $118"

    {
       country: "IRELAND",
       costs: "$125 is the average daily price for traveling in Ireland. The average price of food for one day is $36. The average price of a hotel for a couple is $122"
    },
    {
       country: "HUNGARY",
       costs: "$84 is the average daily price for traveling in Hungary. The average price of food for one day is $19. The average price of a hotel for a couple is $95"
    },
    {
       country: "CANADA",
       costs: "$127 is the average daily price for traveling in Canada. The average price of food for one day is $27. The average price of a hotel for a couple is $130"
    },
    {
      country: "VIETNAM",
      costs: "$41 is the average daily price for traveling in Vietnam. The average price of food for one day is $9.66. The average price of a hotel for a couple is $42"
    }
];

var handlers = {
  'LaunchRequest': function () {
    this.emit(':askWithCard', 'Welcome to Travel Helper. Tell me what country your going to. I will tell you how much you need on average to spend on food and accommodation. ', 'Tell me what country your are going to and I will tell you much you need on average to spend on food and accomodation', 'Travel Helper Guide', 'What country are you going to? I will tell you much you need on average to spend on food and accomodation');
  },
  'TravelCosts': function() {
    var countrySlot = this.event.request.intent.slots.country.value;
    if(countrySlot === "undefined") {
      this.emit(':tell', 'Sorry this does not exist');
        } else {
          this.emit(':tellWithCard', getSuggestion(skillData, 'country', countrySlot.toUpperCase()).costs, 'country','costs');
        }
  }
};

exports.handler = function(event, context){
  var alexa = Alexa.handler(event, context);
  alexa.registerHandlers(handlers);
  alexa.execute();
};

function getSuggestion(data, propName, propValue) {
  for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i][propName] == propValue) {
      return data[i];
    }
  }
}
```

I am using the AMAZON.County slot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing `countrySlot` to a string `"undefined"` instead of `undefined`, removing the `"` might solve your problem. But when the `countrySlot` is defined, it will result to error if the country in your `skillData` was not found.

You can check if the country exist by looking for its index when the `countrySlot !== undefined`. Else tell the user that the country is not in the list.

```
var countrySlot = this.event.request.intent.slots.country.value;

if(countrySlot !== undefined && skillData.findIndex(element => element.country === countrySlot.toUpperCase()) >= 0) {
  console.log(`country ${countrySlot} exist`);
  this.emit(':tellWithCard', getSuggestion(skillData, 'country', countrySlot.toUpperCase()).costs, 'country','costs');
} 
else {
  console.log(`can't find country: ${countrySlot} in skillData`);
  this.emit(':tell', 'Sorry this does not exist');
}
```